# Bash: Search and replace password in a .txt file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, change-password

I'm trying to figure out how to search and replace a password on a specific line and specific column in a .txt file. This is what it looks like:

```
Admin1 Pass1 1
Admin2 Pass2 1
User1 Upass1 0
User2 Upass2 0
```

---

And here is my code:

```
while (true)
do
read -p 'Whose password would you like to change? Enter the corresponding user name.' readUser
userCheck=$(grep $readUser users.txt)

if [ "$userCheck" ]
then
    echo $userCheck > temp2.txt

    read -p 'Enter the old password' oldPass
        passCheck=$(awk '{print$2}' temp2.txt)

    if [ "$passCheck" == "$oldPass" ]
    then  

        read -p 'Enter the new password' newPass                
        sed -i "/^$readUser/ s/$oldPass/$newPass/" users.txt
        break
    else 
        echo 'The username and/or password do not match. Please try again.'
    fi
else 
    echo 'The username and/or password do not match. Please try again.'
fi
done
```

Assuming User1's password is being replaced with TESTING, this is the result:

```
Admin1 Pass1 1 Admin2 Pass2 1 User1 TESTING 0 User2 Upass2 0
```

What I need is this:

```
Admin1 Pass1 1
Admin2 Pass2 1
User1 TESTING 0
User2 Upass2 0
```

Comment: This has to do with missing quotation. However, you could simply replace your last 2 lines by : `sed -i "s/$oldPass/$newPass/g" users.txt`. The `-i` flag for sed means in-place and will directly save the changes to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original script was almost worked, and only lacked correct quotation. You could have written : `echo "$updatePass" > data` with the double quotes to preserve the newlines. More info on quotation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes)

However, there is room for improvement in your script. You could have written something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

while (true)
do
    read -p 'Whose password would you like to change?' readUser

    # no need for a temporary variable here
    if [ "$(awk -v a="$readUser" '$1==a{print $1}' users.txt)" ] 
    then
        read -p 'Enter the old password' oldPass
        # the awk code checks if the $oldPass matches the recorded password 
        if [ "$oldPass" == "$(awk -v a="$readUser" '$1==a{print $2}' users.txt)" ]
        then 
            read -p 'Enter the new password' newPass
            # the -i flag for sed allows in-place substitution
            # we look for the line begining by $readUser, in case several users have the same password
            sed -i "/^$readUser/ s/$oldPass/$newPass/" users.txt
            break
        else 
            echo 'The username and/or password do not match. Please try again.'
        fi
    else 
        echo 'The username and/or password do not match. Please try again.'
    fi
done
```

Comment: I tried implementing the above solution, but I'm still getting the same unwanted output. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Then this must be related to another part of your code. As of now, I simply coped & pasted this code in a shell script and used it against your sample input.

Comment: I posted the revised code. Using your improved code provided the same results as only changing my code to use sed -i, so I've decided to use that just for simplicity for now.

Comment: I noticed my code uses the file `user.txt`. This typo must be why you see no change in the output. i'll edit my answer

Comment: Copying + Pasting your code allows it to run perfectly. However, when I try to implement it into my own it fails to work. Perhaps something is going wrong in my if statements? The issue was not with the "user.txt", I caught that myself and changed it, yet it still didn't provide the results that I needed

Comment: Problem fixed. Something was wrong with my file. I did the same thing in a new one and it worked perfectly.